# PHP getenv('HOSTNAME')

Tags: php, linux, environment-variables

In CLI mode `getenv('HOSTNAME')` returns *HOSTNAME* environment variable correctly, but when called in script returns `FALSE`.

Why? How can I get the HOSTNAME variable in script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HOSTNAME` is not a CGI environment variable, hence not present in normal PHP scripts.

But you can alternatively use

```
$hostname = `hostname`;     // exec backticks
```

Or read the system config file:

```
$hostname = file_get_contents("/etc/hostname");   // also only U*ix
```

But most PHP scripts should just use `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` or the client-requested `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me. I think I'll go with SERVER_NAME instead.

Comment: `/etc/hostname` is very linuxy. Don't count on U*ix having it.

Answer (score 7):

The HOSTNAME is not available in the environment used by Apache, though it usually IS available in the environment used by the CLI.

For [PHP >= 5.3.0 use this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php):

`$hostname = gethostname();`

For [PHP < 5.3.0 but >= 4.2.0 use this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php):

`$hostname = php_uname('n');`

For PHP < 4.2.0 use this:

```
$hostname = getenv('HOSTNAME'); 
if(!$hostname) $hostname = trim(`hostname`); 
if(!$hostname) $hostname = exec('echo $HOSTNAME');
if(!$hostname) $hostname = preg_replace('#^\w+\s+(\w+).*$#', '$1', exec('uname -a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your environment is likely cleaned in the webserver or php-fcgi/fpm start up script, so that sensitive information about the startup account is not leaked to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `HTTP_HOST` which then is empty when you access it in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this maybe?

```
function getHostName()
{
  //if we are in the shell return the env hostname
  if(array_key_exists('SHELL', $_ENV))
  {
     return getenv('HOSTNAME');
  }
  return $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There also exists an `ENV` variable you can access via `<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>`.
But I get the same thing: cli has more variable than the server, but it must be configuration issue.